# ejs doesn't return the full string thats passed

Tags: node.js, ejs

```
<form class="item" action="/" method="post">

    <!-- listtitle = March 24, 2020' -->
    <input type="text" name="newItem" value="" placeholder="New item" autocomplete="off">
    <button type="submit" name="list" value= <%= listTitle %> >+</button>
</form>
```

When I perform the post request in the javascript file it works fine locally but when I connect to mongodb online database it doesn't return the full string instead it returns

```
let itemName = req.body.newItem;
let listPathName = req.body.list;
console.log("name of list " + listPathName); // displays March 24,
```

I need to display the full string.

Comment: Please correct `value= <%= listTitle %>` to `value='<%= listTitle %>'`.

Comment: thank you sir..worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Put the ejs tags into a quote, that way you would get the full string

Rather than `value= <%= listTitle %>` use `value='<%= listTitle %>'`